# How to put file manually to iOS persistentDataPath?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, copy-paste, persistent-data

{to the point}
So I want to create some Quiz Game on Unity that the questions data using external file (in this case I using JSON). I want to keep my questions data can access/edit by myself separately. And then I just have to copy-paste it manually to persistentDataPath in iOS but I don't know how to do it. Anyone can help me?

Note : I don't wanna use any script/code to do it, just manually Copy-Paste it...\

thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set "Application Supports iTunes file sharing" key in the info plist of your app in Xcode. 
[image]

...and then you can access persistentDataPath through iTunes.
(In the example screenshot below I copied midi.csv from my MacBook to excel in my iPad)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make it more comfy add a PostProcessBuild-script like [this one (gist)](https://gist.github.com/krisrok/f55ea7cf89010a9f54a9271953f952fd).

It applies the setting after each build, so no manual steps.